# How to transform a '00' to 00 (integrer) in python with ''.join()?

Tags: python, encryption

I'm doing a cryptography app and I need to transform the data that the user give to the program. The idea is that the user write what we would like to encrypt and then this text is transformed in numbers. Then I have to divide this sequence of numbers in sequence of 4 numbers but then I find a problem. Since a to j in alphabet, they have a 0 before the number, like a = 00, b = 01; c = 02... but when I have for example this block ready to go through the encryption algorithm sequence  bc = '0102',  when I use in python de ".join(bc) the result of that is 102 and I need a group of 4 to be encrypted correctly.

Maybe you are thinking why I use that method and that's because I have to use a list before to treat de data like a string, but finally I need them like an integrer.

Here is the code which I use for preparing the information for encryption. If you don't understand anything is Spanish.

```
mensaje=input("Introduce el mensaje que quieres encriptar: ")

mensaje_numeros =[]

for i in mensaje:
    if i == 'a':
        mensaje_numeros.append('00')
    elif i == 'b':
        mensaje_numeros.append('01')
    elif i == 'c':
        mensaje_numeros.append('02')
    elif i == 'd':
        mensaje_numeros.append('03')
    elif i == 'e':
        mensaje_numeros.append('04')
    elif i == 'f':
        mensaje_numeros.append('05')
    elif i == 'g':
        mensaje_numeros.append('06')
    elif i == 'h':
        mensaje_numeros.append('07')
    elif i == 'i':
        mensaje_numeros.append('08')
    elif i == 'j':
        mensaje_numeros.append('09')
    elif i == 'k':
        mensaje_numeros.append('10')
    elif i == 'l':
        mensaje_numeros.append('11')
    elif i == 'm':
        mensaje_numeros.append('12')
    elif i == 'n':
        mensaje_numeros.append('13')
    elif i == 'o':
        mensaje_numeros.append('14')
    elif i == 'p':
        mensaje_numeros.append('15')
    elif i == 'q':
        mensaje_numeros.append('16')
    elif i == 'r':
        mensaje_numeros.append('17')
    elif i == 's':
        mensaje_numeros.append('18')
    elif i == 't':
        mensaje_numeros.append('19')
    elif i == 'u':
        mensaje_numeros.append('20')
    elif i == 'v':
        mensaje_numeros.append('21')
    elif i == 'w':
        mensaje_numeros.append('22')
    elif i == 'x':
        mensaje_numeros.append('23')
    elif i == 'y':
        mensaje_numeros.append('24')
    elif i == 'z':
        mensaje_numeros.append('25')
    elif i == '_':
        mensaje_numeros.append('26')



bloque_encriptacion = []
contador = 0
while len(mensaje_numeros) != 0:
    while (contador <=3) and (len(mensaje_numeros) != 0):
        bloque_encriptacion.append(mensaje_numeros[0])
        contador += len(mensaje_numeros[0])
        mensaje_numeros.pop(0)
        

    contador = 0

    bloque_encriptacion = int(''.join(bloque_encriptacion))
    """Here goes the encrypt althgorithym"""
    bloque_encriptacion = []
```

Comment: Why is this a problem? Don't convert the string to an integer and you should be fine.

Comment: No because the encrypt alghorithym needs an integer not a string

Comment: And what is the problem there? That is what you're doing. Are you asking because you anticipate an issue when decrypting?

Comment: I'm asking because I need an integer to operate with them and I need that de integer have 4 digits and I need de 0's before. It won't work if I use a string